# React switch in render: div children no styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so in my render() function I have a switch to conditionally load different components based on a type, the problem is that for one of the cases I had to render 2 components, so I wrapped them in a div, by doing so they lose the class that was assigned to them `inputField`, this is how the code is looking:

```
{(() => {
                switch (values.type) {
                  case "sole":
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <InputMask
                          className={classNames(
                            styles.inputField,
                            styles.override
                          )}
                        >
                          {() => (
                            <LNTextField
                              type="text"
                            />
                          )}
                        </InputMask>
                        <InputMask
                          className={classNames(
                            styles.inputField,
                            styles.override
                          )}
                        >
                          {() => (
                            <LNTextField
                              name="dob"
                              type="text"
                            />
                          )}
                        </InputMask>
                      </div>
                    );
                  default:
                    return null;
                }
              })()}
```

I removed alot of the functional bits of the code since this is a styling issue, why are the InputMasks not having the inputField class applied now that they're in a `div` and how can I fix this?

This is how the style looks, im using override to increase priority;

```
.inputField.override {
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style rules you have in place may be so specific that they won't work if a random `div` is in the way. This is usually due to using child or sibling selectors.

As a solution, you can use the `<React.Fragment>` wrapper instead of a `<div>` to wrap your items. The shorthand for this is simply `<>`.

```
<>
  <MyFirstComponent />
  <MySecondComponent />
</>
```

Comment: Alright I did this, it fixed the fact that div was setting display to block for them, but aside from that the classes are still not being applied.

Comment: Alright, so moving the class onto the LNTextField instead of the InputMask worked, this is weird as it worked on the InputMask before having to wrap them but regardless it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Fragment>` tag to wrap them instead of `<div>` tag. It was introduced in React [v16.2](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1620-november-28-2017).

If you are currently using an earlier version, you can also wrap them as an array of elements.

Comment: Import Fragment from?

Comment: Your import should look like this:
`import React, { Fragment } from 'react';`

Comment: This classes are still missing although in a Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Approach if you don't want to use React.Fragment and  then,
You can also create a Auxiliary HOC to wrap the component

```
const Aux = (props) => props.children;

export default Aux;

<Aux>
  <MyFirstComponent />
  <MySecondComponent />
<Aux>
```